# Rename confirm button on global action

Tags: community-builder, label

I've got a global action being used in a community built with community builder. The submit button for the record creation is "Confirm" I'd like to change this but it doesn't look like it's editable in the component and I couldn't find a label in salesforce I could change. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to change this confirm button text?

Answer (score -1):

It's a little bit hidden...

Go to the Global Action

You have to change the Description on "none"  then you can use your own Description.

regards john